# Webview Custom Back Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to make custom back button in WebView.
Its any way to get OnBackPress with custom button?
Just have a full screen webview, and i want to make button to going back in the webview.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use a Floating action button and on click set the logic that onBackPress() does

Comment: Create a button, and in its `onClick`, put  `if (webView.canGoBack()) webView.goBack();`, that's it.